# Graphic for Android/iPhone

Tags: android, iphone, smartphone

I'm making a illustrated instruction for how to use an app that will be needed
for Android/iPhone

I'm not much into coding for Android and I though the client just needed the 
illustration but he asks:

"We will need the illustration saved to a file that we can run on mobile devices (iPhone/Android) as well as the source code."

Isn't jpg enough? is there some additional code that you android programmers are
aware of?

Answer (score 0):

No. In Android you can just use a [Drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html). This can be a number of different file formats, including  your jpeg. It may be good to have a look at [Android Asset Studio](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html). With this tool you can get a nice zip file for all your different screen densities. If you keep the file structure that asset studio outputs then Android will do all the heavy lifting for you.

It might also help you to know something about [9-patches](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html). This is how Android knows how to resize and stretch your image. Asset Studio has an option to set this as well.